# Converting a time_t to a string in a given format in C

Tags: c, string, time, posix

So as part of an assignment we've been given this skeleton function to complete:

```
char *time2str(time_t time) {
    static char *str_fmt = "%02d/%02d/%4d %02d:%02d";
    char *time_s = ""; // appropriate string allocation here

    return time_s;
}
```

However I'm very new to C and struggling to get my head around what I'm doing wrong (and also how pointers work)... I've been trying to use `localtime` to get a `struct` with which I can access the specific values I need to add to the string in the given format. Something like this:

```
char *time2str(time_t time) {
    static char *str_fmt = "%02d/%02d/%4d %02d:%02d";

    struct tm *info;
    info = localtime(&time);

    char *time_s = (str_fmt, info->tm_mday, info->tm_mon...etc...);

    return time_s;
}
```

However I'm just getting warnings and errors at compile no matter what I try and do (remove `str_fmt` and just put the format in quotations at the beginning of `time_s`, using `info.tm_mday` etc rather than `info->tm_mday`). However nothing seems to have any effect and I can't find anything online that helps me solve the problem in the way we have been asked.

Can anyone help? It's probably worth mentioning that we are doing this on MINIX 3.2.1 using MINIX system calls.

Comment: interesting, the upper block of code is exactly how it was given to us as a 'skeleton' implementation, I was assuming it was all correct

Comment: I think your teacher wants you to allocate with `malloc` and then use `sprintf`.

Comment: If only POSIX had [`asprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html). Alas, it is not POSIX. (Although, it is available in Linux/GNU/macOS/most *BSDs.) I wonder how many buffer overruns would be avoided, if we used it instead of `malloc()`+`snprintf()` (or worse, `sprintf()`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using what you've given us, I assume the function should be:

```
char *time2str(time_t time) {
    static char *str_fmt = "%02d/%02d/%4d %02d:%02d";

    // Convert to struct tm
    // localtime returns a pointer, so shallow copy to info
    struct tm info = *localtime(&time);

    // Allocate memory for ##/##/#### ##:##
    char *time_s = malloc(17);  // Space for 16 chars and eos
    if (NULL == time_s) {// Handle error.....}
    sprintf(time_s, str_fmt, info.tm_mon + 1, info.tm_mday, 1900 + info.tm_year,
           info.tm_hour, info.tm_min);

    return time_s;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I had just about implemented this same thing using your comments above and am no longer getting compile errors. think this has helped me grasp a few concepts of C a little better too (coming from Java) :)

Answer (score 0):

Managing strings is a tricky task in C.  Code with years of success can fail when an unexpected situation exist.

Consider the format `"%02d/%02d/%4d %02d:%02d"`.  This would usually expect an array of size 16 + 1 (for the null character).  This is the same type of coding that made for [Y2K bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) as this one needs more space after the year 9999.  Consider a system  that allowed `time_t` to represent time into the far future and and tried forming a date/time string based in its max value --> buffer overflow.

Instead, allow for all potential values in `struct tm` and  provide a generous temporary buffer.  Then allocate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

// Max length needed for a `int` as decimal text 
#define INT_STR_LEN (sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 2)

#define TIME2STR_FMT "%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d"
// Worst case size - and them some
#define TIME2STR_SZ (sizeof TIME2STR_FMT + 5*INT_STR_LEN)

char *time2str(time_t time) {

  struct tm *info = localtime(&time);
  if (info == NULL) return NULL;

  char buf[TIME2STR_SZ];
  int n = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, TIME2STR_FMT, info->tm_mon + 1, info->tm_mday,
      info->tm_year + 1900, info->tm_hour, info->tm_min);
  if (n < 0 || n >= sizeof buf) return NULL;

  // Allocate and copy
  size_t sz = strlen(buf) + 1;
  char *time_s = malloc(sz);
  if (time_s) {
    memcpy(time_s, buf, sz);
  }

  return time_s;
}

int main(void) {
  time_t t;
  puts(time2str(time(&t)));
  return 0;
}
```